# Requiring Scala implicit class in a function

Tags: scala, implicit

My goal is to equip a variety of types (Timestamps, Dates, etc.) with nice properties they might not have by default (ordering, -, etc.). I'm doing something like this:

```
trait NiceProperties[T] {
  def -(t: T): Double
  def +(d: Double): T
  ...
}

implicit class BetterTimestamp(val t: Timestamp) extends NiceProperties[Timestamp] {
  override def -(Timestamp): ...
}
```

This all works fine until I need to pass it into a function that assumes `NiceProperties`:

```
def myUtil[T](t: NiceProperties[T]): T = {
  (t + 1.0) + 1.0
}
```

This now fails, because the function lacks the implicit evidence that the class `T` can be implicitly upcast to `NiceProperties[T]`, so it can't add `(t + 1.0): T` to a double.

Is there a way to pass evidence for an implicit class into a function? Alternatively, is there a better pattern for this?

Comment: Would letting `NiceProperties.+` return `NiceProperties[T]` instead of `T` solve your issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could solve your issue by turning your `NiceProperties[T]` into a class that knows how to add, sum, ... two values of type `T`:

```
trait NiceProperties[T] {
  def subtract(a: T, b: T): Double
  def add(a: T, d: Double): T
}
```

You can now create an implicit `NiceProperties` object or val for Timestamps, Dates, ...

```
object BetterTimestamp extends NiceProperties[Timestamp] {
  def subtract(a: Timestamp, b: Timestamp): Double = ???
  def add(a: Timestamp, d: Double): Timestamp = ???
}
```

In your example method you'll request an implicit `NiceProperties[T]` which does the operations for your.

```
def myUtil[T](t: T)(implicit prop: NiceProperties[T]): T = {
  prop.add(prop.add(t, 1.0), 1.0)
}
```

Since this is ugly, you can use an implicit class to add the `+`, `-`, ... operators to any class where an implicit `NiceProperties[T]` is available:

```
implicit class NicePropertiesOps[T](t: T)(implicit prop: NiceProperties[T]) {
  def +(d: Double): T = prop.add(t, d)
  def -(b: T): Double = prop.subtract(t, b)
}
```

Now your example from above should work almost as you described.

```
def myUtil[T : NiceProperties](t: T): T = {
  (t + 1.0) + 1.0
}
```

https://scastie.scala-lang.org/0D1Y9sE5S5mrzm9coZPMWw

Comment: It should be noted that this is the [type class pattern](https://blog.scalac.io/2017/04/19/typeclasses-in-scala.html).

Comment: I would like to point out that is better to use an implicit val with an explicit type signature instead of an implicit object.

Answer (score 3):

@Aki's answer is completely correct. Here is just an alternative approach of bringing the conversion into scope. This way is used in `Numeric` typeclass.

```
class Timestamp

trait NiceProperties[T] {
  def subtract(a: T, b: T): Double
  def add(a: T, d: Double): T

  implicit class Ops(t:T) {
    def +(d: Double): T = add(t, d)
    def -(b: T): Double = subtract(t, b)
  }

}

implicit object BetterTimestamp extends NiceProperties[Timestamp] {
  def subtract(a: Timestamp, b: Timestamp): Double = ???
  def add(a: Timestamp, d: Double): Timestamp = ???
}

def myUtil[T](t: T)(implicit prop: NiceProperties[T]): T = {
  import prop._
  (t + 1.0) + 1.0
}
```

and one more approach just of fun. This is how to avoid import:

```
trait NiceProperties[T] extends (T => Ops[T]) {
  def subtract(a: T, b: T): Double
  def add(a: T, d: Double): T

  implicit val v = this
  def apply(t:T) = new Ops(t)

}

class Ops[T](t:T)(implicit prop: NiceProperties[T]) {
  def +(d: Double): T = prop.add(t, d)
  def -(b: T): Double = prop.subtract(t, b)
}

implicit object BetterTimestamp extends NiceProperties[Timestamp] {
  def subtract(a: Timestamp, b: Timestamp): Double = ???
  def add(a: Timestamp, d: Double): Timestamp = ???
}

def myUtil[T:NiceProperties](t: T): T = {
  (t + 1.0) + 1.0
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The existing answers are good, but, in cases where you can't modify the trait, you can require the implicit conversion as a parameter:

```
def myUtil[T](t: T)(implicit conv: T => NiceProperties[T]) = t + 1.0 + 1.0
```

If you're doing this a lot, you might add an abstract type so you can use a context bound:

```
type HasNiceProperties[T] = T => NiceProperties[T]
def myUtil[T : HasNiceProperties](t: T) = t + 1.0 + 1.0
```

Comment: I'm not sure it works as expected. `conv: T => NiceProperties[T]` converts T to NiceProperties but there is no `+(d: Double)` operation inside NiceProperties.

Comment: @BogdanVakulenko Not sure what you mean. In the original question, `NiceProperties` has `def +(d: Double): T`.

Comment: Got it. Just spent some time trying to understand solution based on your proposal.  Interesting approach.